# drag and drop event fires twice

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, draggable, jquery-ui-draggable

I am working on a script where i am having an issue while drag and drop list items.When i drag and item into a drop able area then event fires twice. here is my code.SEE CODE HERE

```
$('.draglist div').draggable({        
    cursor: 'move',
    helper: 'clone',
    connectToSortable: '.droplist'
}); 
$(".droplist").droppable({
drop: function (event, ui) {
  var dragtext = $(ui.draggable).text();
  alert(dragtext);
}
});
$('.droplist').sortable({
     opacity: 0.6,
     revert: true,
     cursor: 'move',
     placeholder: "highlight",
 });
```

[See DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/btechguy/3k5aanLn/3/)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2678598/jquery-draggable-get-its-content-js-fired-twice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a jQuery UI bug. A simple work-around is to use the use the [sortable `receive` event](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#event-receive) rather than the droppable `drop` event. In doing so, the event is only fired once.

[**Updated Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/fm5vpwet/)

```
$(".droplist").droppable().sortable({
  opacity: 0.6,
  revert: true,
  cursor: 'move',
  placeholder: "highlight",
  receive: function(event, ui) {
    var dragtext = $(ui.item[0]).text();
    alert(dragtext);
  }
});
```

Comment: this solution works but problem is that i have to add bunch of div code into droplist, by using this code its adding divs to draglist instead of droplist, i am copying this code to wordpress and its adding div html to draglist instead of droplist.